# latexmk.pl version error

Tags: latexmk, vscode, perl

I am trying to use `LaTeX` with VSCode, but I cannot seem to get the .tex file to build.
I have installed the latest Perl 5.8.8, installed and updated (both user and admin) `MiKTeX` and installed the `LaTeX` Workshop extension. Yet I am getting this error:

> File::Path version 2.08 required--this is only version 1.08 at C:\Users\dell\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\scripts\latexmk\latexmk.pl line 75.
> BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at C:\Users\dell\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\scripts\latexmk\latexmk.pl line 75.

The file `latexmk.pl` shows version 4.80, but I don't seem to understand this error.

EDIT:
This is what the line 75 in the latexmk.pl says:

```
use File::Path 2.08 qw( make_path );
```

EDIT EDIT:
I checked that there is an option on the LaTeX Workshop extension on VSCode to use pdflatex to build instead of latexmk. Should i just use that?

Comment: it is your file::path module that is too old.

Comment: wait... how do i upgrade that?

Comment: if you have a free standing perl you could update via cpan but I have no idea what perl is used by miktex as I don't have miktex

Comment: i uninstalled TexLive and then installed MikTeX. Since then, i have been getting this issue.

Comment: i will try uninstalling miktex and installing texlive again, will see if that works.

Comment: You say you've installed Perl 5.8.8.  The current version is 5.36.1.  So you should install an up-to-date version of Perl before trying anything else.  (And probably uninstall your old version.)

Comment: A difference between MiKTeX and TeXLive is that MiKTeX contains no Perl distribution, whereas TeXLive for Windows contains its own Perl, which it uses for Perl scripts like latexmk (and many others).  The version of Perl in TeXLive is currently 5.34.0. With MiKTeX you need a separate installation of Perl.

Comment: I've corrected the tags in the question, so that there's a latexmk tag instead of a latexml tag.