# Create a new glossary

Tags: glossaries

I would like to create a personalized glossary (because I would like to create two different glossaries).

I first tried the Overleaf tutorial (https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Glossaries) and it works for me.

I then tried to reproduce this tutorial: [Glossaries package, Multiple glossaries mixing up entries](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/322202/glossaries-package-multiple-glossaries-mixing-up-entries) but I fail to manage creating a new glossary.

Here is a minimal example:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{report}
\usepackage[toc]{glossaries}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%% Trying creating my glossary

\newglossary*{type1}{Title One} % or \newglossary[tld]{type1}{pref1}{ntn1}{Title One}
\makeglossaries

\newglossaryentry{pref1:latex}{
    type=type1,
    name=latex,
    description={Is a markup language specially suited for 
scientific documents}
}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%% Normal

%\makeglossaries
%
%\newglossaryentry{latex}{
%    name=latex,
%    description={Is a markup language specially suited for 
%scientific documents}
%}

\begin{document}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

The
%\Gls{latex}
\Gls{pref1:latex}
typesetting markup language is specially suitable for documents that include maths.

%\printglossary
\printglossary[type=type1]


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\end{document}
```

Normal version is the one inspired from Overleaf (the one commented); the one uncommented is what I tried to do to create my new glossary from the stackexhange question.

When I run MakeIndex, I get the following message:

```
Process started
This is makeindex, version 2.16 [MiKTeX 23.5]. Scanning style file ./build/test3.ist...........................
done (27 attributes redefined, 0 ignored). Scanning input file build/test3.glo...done (0 entries accepted, 0 rejected). Nothing written in build/test3.gls. Transcript written in build/test3.glg.
Process exited normally
```

Can somebody help me?
Thank you!

Comment: With this command : `makeindex -t build/%.esp -s build/%.ist -o build/%.outesp build/%.inesp`, I could print the glossary named `\newglossary[esp]{glsesp}{outesp}{inesp}{Glosario}`

However, on TexMaker, I cannot use MakeIndex to print multiple glossaries!

Comment: Use `makeglossaries` and let the script figure out what needs to be done ;). Each glossary has to be done separately. The script will cycle through them. If you reference 'the Overleaf tutorial', please link. There is more than one!

Comment: The link has been added!

Answer (score 1):

The most straightforward way to generate the glossaries is to use `makeglossaries` rather than `makeindex` (or `xindy`).

```
makeglossaries <main document name>
```

where `<main document name>` is the name of your `.tex` file without the `.tex` extension. `makeglossaries` will figure out whether to use `makeindex` or `xindy`, what options to use and which glossary files to process.

Then your code produces the expected result

[image: glossary produced with makeglossaries]

Comment: I am a TexMaker user, and it asks me to install `perl`: is it really necessary? Is it the one mentioned on that page: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/410606/texmaker-makeglossaries-the-script-engine-could-not-be-found
Because the link goes to a website requiring an account to download... It seems a bit weird for a LaTeX use...

Comment: @Alex `perl` is standard for a TeX installation. If you have Tex Live, you certainly have it installed already. I'd assume MikTeX is the same, but I'm not certain. It's widely used for scripts precisely because people should already have it, if they have TeX at all. Most likely, TeXMaker can't find it and it's a path issue. (But, as I say, I'm not sure MikTeX has it - I'd just assume it does, given how things work.)

Comment: @Alex According to https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/684548/latexmk-pl-version-error#comment1698465_684548, MikTeX does not include `perl`. I'd suggest trying `makeglossaries-lite` first and then see about `perl` if the result is unsatisfactory.

Comment: @Alex Unlike texlive miktex doesn't include perl, so you need to install an external one for perl scripts like makeglossaries.

Comment: @Alex https://www.perl.org/get.html. I don't know if one or other version is recommended over the other.

Comment: Can this MikTex package work? https://miktex.org/packages/perltex
Because my computer does not appreciate the link perl.org/get.html ...

Comment: @Alex No, because that package doesn't provide `perl`. It requires `perl`, but it is just a script. In what sense doesn't your computer appreciate the link? You mean it refuses to visit that part of the web?